# What is the most efficient way to reorder a contiguous strided pixel array?

Tags: c, optimization, neon, darknet

I am working on a highly performance-critical image processing pipeline on a Jetson TX2 (with an ARM processor), which involves reading a set of images and then performing deep learning based object detection through [Darknet](https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet/). Darknet, written in C, has its own representation of how images are stored, which is different from how OpenCV's IplImage or a Python numpy array would store the images.

In my application, I am required to interface with Darknet through Python. So, as of now, I am reading a 'batch' of images (usually 16) into a numpy array and then passing it to Darknet as a contiguous array using ctypes. Within Darknet, I then have to rearrange the ordering of the pixels to go from the numpy format to Darknet's format.

While the input array is one contiguous block arranged column-wise, then row-wise, then channel-wise, and then by image, the Darknet format needs to be arranged by channel first, then by column, then by row: and contains one row per image in the batch instead of a contiguous block. The picture below tries to demonstrate the difference. In this example, I assume a single `ixj` image. (0,0), (0,1) etc. indicate (row, col), whereas in the top, C0, C1, C2.. etc indicate the column in the corresponding row. Note that in the case of multiple images as part of a batch, the input format arranges them sequentially one after the other, but Darknet needs them to be on separate rows: each row containing data from only one image.

[image]

As of now, my code in C that converts the input array to the Darknet format looks like this, where it iteratively hits every pixel in every channel and puts it in a different place, while also normalizing the pixels along the way.

```
matrix ndarray_to_matrix(unsigned char* src, long* shape, long* strides)
{
int nb = shape[0];    // Batch size
int h = shape[1];     // Height of each image
int w = shape[2];     // Width of each image
int c = shape[3];     // No. of channels in each image
matrix X = make_matrix(nb, h*w*c);     // Output array format: 2D

int step_b = strides[0];
int step_h = strides[1];
int step_w = strides[2];
int step_c = strides[3];

int b, i, j, k;
int index1, index2 = 0;

for(b = 0; b < nb ; ++b) {
    for(i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        for(k= 0; k < c; ++k) {
            for(j = 0; j < w; ++j) {
                index1 = k*w*h + i*w + j;
                index2 = step_b*b + step_h*i + step_w*j + step_c*k;
                X.vals[b][index1] = src[index2]/255.;
            }
        }
    }
}
return X;
}
```

**Is there a more efficient way of doing this rearranging and normalization in C?**

- I am using the Jetson TX2: which contains an ARM processor and an NVIDIA GPU, thus having access to NEON and CUDA as well as OpenMP.
- The image dimensions are fixed and can be hardcoded: only the batch size can change.

Comment: If you are open to CUDA or neon solutions, you might want to add those tags.

Comment: I initially did, but they were edited out for some reason.. re-added them.

Comment: It's a piece of cake with NEON. It will be so fast that it will be bandwidth limited even when running on a single ARM core, and thus, CUDA is really unnecessary.

Comment: What's the image dimension? Is there no alpha channel?

Comment: The images are 640x360x3 each, each pixel is a byte. No alpha channel.

Comment: Is the stride for destination? Do you need it at all? Can you guarantee an alignment of 32bytes for both src and dst?

Comment: Are you referring to the array strides? That just encodes how many bytes I need to 'jump' to get to the next row, column, or channel: for example, reading the green channel of pixel 0,0 means I need to jump 640*360 bytes. As to your second question, I am not sure: can I check that? Also, I note here that src is 1 byte per pixel, dst becomes 4 because of the normalization and storing as a float. I can also pad the src values if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The function below will be almost as fast as `memcpy`:

```
/*
 *  Created on: 2018. 5. 5.
 *      Author: Jake 'Alquimista' Lee
 */

    .arch   armv8-a
    .text
    .global alquimista_ndarray_to_matrix

// void alquimista_ndarray_to_matrix(uint8_t * pDst, uint8_t *pSrc);

pDst    .req    x0
pRed    .req    x1
pGrn    .req    x2
pBlu    .req    x3
count   .req    w4

.balign 64
.func
alquimista_ndarray_to_matrix:
    mov     x16, #(640*360) & 0xffff
    str     q8, [sp, #-16]!
    movk    x16, #((640*360)>>16), lsl #16
    mov     count, #(640*360)/128
    add     pGrn, pRed, x16
    add     pBlu, pRed, x16, lsl #1
    b       1f

.balign 64
1:
    ldp     q0, q3, [pRed], #32
    ldp     q1, q4, [pGrn], #32
    ldp     q2, q5, [pBlu], #32

    ldp     q6, q16, [pRed], #32
    ldp     q7, q17, [pGrn], #32
    ldp     q8, q18, [pBlu], #32

    ldp     q19, q22, [pRed], #32
    ldp     q20, q23, [pGrn], #32
    ldp     q21, q24, [pBlu], #32

    ldp     q25, q28, [pRed], #32
    ldp     q26, q29, [pGrn], #32
    ldp     q27, q30, [pBlu], #32

    subs    count, count, #1

    st3     {v0.16b, v1.16b, v2.16b}, [pDst], #48
    st3     {v3.16b, v4.16b, v5.16b}, [pDst], #48
    st3     {v6.16b, v7.16b, v8.16b}, [pDst], #48
    st3     {v16.16b, v17.16b, v18.16b}, [pDst], #48

    st3     {v19.16b, v20.16b, v21.16b}, [pDst], #48
    st3     {v22.16b, v23.16b, v24.16b}, [pDst], #48
    st3     {v25.16b, v26.16b, v27.16b}, [pDst], #48
    st3     {v28.16b, v29.16b, v30.16b}, [pDst], #48
    b.gt    1b

.balign 8
    ldr     q8, [sp], #16
    ret
.endfunc
.end
```

---

For maximum performance and minimum power consumption, you might want to align the source pointer to 32 bytes and the destination to 16 bytes.

The function prototype is:

`void alquimista_ndarray_to_matrix(uint8_t * pDst, uint8_t *pSrc);`

---

Below is the function that does the conversion to `float` on the fly.

And I added the batch number as parameter so that you don't have to do a function call for every image.

```
/*
 *  Created on: 2018. 5. 5.
 *      Copyright: Jake 'Alquimista' Lee. All rights reserved
 */

    .arch   armv8-a
    .text
    .global alquimista_ndarray_to_matrix_float

// void alquimista_ndarray_to_matrix_float(float *pDst, uint8_t *pSrc, uint32_t batch);

pDst    .req    x0
pRed    .req    x1
batch   .req    w2
pGrn    .req    x3
pBlu    .req    x4
stride  .req    x5
count   .req    w7

.balign 64
.func
alquimista_ndarray_to_matrix_float:
    mov     stride, #((640*360)<<1) & 0xffff
    stp     q8, q15, [sp, #-32]!
    movk    stride, #((640*360)>>15), lsl #16
    mov     count, #(640*360)/32
    add     pGrn, pRed, stride, lsr #1
    add     pBlu, pRed, stride
    b       1f

.balign 64
1:
    ldp     q0, q1, [pRed], #32
    ldp     q2, q3, [pGrn], #32
    ldp     q4, q5, [pBlu], #32

    subs    count, count, #1

    ushll   v20.8h, v0.8b, #7
    ushll2  v23.8h, v0.16b, #7
    ushll   v26.8h, v1.8b, #7
    ushll2  v29.8h, v1.16b, #7
    ushll   v21.8h, v2.8b, #7
    ushll2  v24.8h, v2.16b, #7
    ushll   v27.8h, v3.8b, #7
    ushll2  v30.8h, v3.16b, #7
    ushll   v22.8h, v4.8b, #7
    ushll2  v25.8h, v4.16b, #7
    ushll   v28.8h, v5.8b, #7
    ushll2  v31.8h, v5.16b, #7

    ursra   v20.8h, v20.8h, #8
    ursra   v21.8h, v21.8h, #8
    ursra   v22.8h, v22.8h, #8
    ursra   v23.8h, v23.8h, #8
    ursra   v24.8h, v24.8h, #8
    ursra   v25.8h, v25.8h, #8
    ursra   v26.8h, v26.8h, #8
    ursra   v27.8h, v27.8h, #8
    ursra   v28.8h, v28.8h, #8
    ursra   v29.8h, v29.8h, #8
    ursra   v30.8h, v30.8h, #8
    ursra   v31.8h, v31.8h, #8

    uxtl    v0.4s, v20.4h
    uxtl    v1.4s, v21.4h
    uxtl    v2.4s, v22.4h
    uxtl2   v3.4s, v20.8h
    uxtl2   v4.4s, v21.8h
    uxtl2   v5.4s, v22.8h

    uxtl    v6.4s, v23.4h
    uxtl    v7.4s, v24.4h
    uxtl    v8.4s, v25.4h
    uxtl2   v15.4s, v23.8h
    uxtl2   v16.4s, v24.8h
    uxtl2   v17.4s, v25.8h

    uxtl    v18.4s, v26.4h
    uxtl    v19.4s, v27.4h
    uxtl    v20.4s, v28.4h
    uxtl2   v21.4s, v26.8h
    uxtl2   v22.4s, v27.8h
    uxtl2   v23.4s, v28.8h

    uxtl    v24.4s, v29.4h
    uxtl    v25.4s, v30.4h
    uxtl    v26.4s, v31.4h
    uxtl2   v27.4s, v29.8h
    uxtl2   v28.4s, v30.8h
    uxtl2   v29.4s, v31.8h

    ucvtf   v0.4s, v0.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v1.4s, v1.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v2.4s, v2.4s, #15

    ucvtf   v3.4s, v3.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v4.4s, v4.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v5.4s, v5.4s, #15

    ucvtf   v6.4s, v6.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v7.4s, v7.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v8.4s, v8.4s, #15

    ucvtf   v15.4s, v15.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v16.4s, v16.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v17.4s, v17.4s, #15

    ucvtf   v18.4s, v18.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v19.4s, v19.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v20.4s, v20.4s, #15

    ucvtf   v21.4s, v21.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v22.4s, v22.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v23.4s, v23.4s, #15

    ucvtf   v24.4s, v24.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v25.4s, v25.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v26.4s, v26.4s, #15

    ucvtf   v27.4s, v27.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v28.4s, v28.4s, #15
    ucvtf   v29.4s, v29.4s, #15

    st3     {v0.4s - v2.4s}, [pDst], #48
    st3     {v3.4s - v5.4s}, [pDst], #48
    st3     {v6.4s - v8.4s}, [pDst], #48
    st3     {v15.4s - v17.4s}, [pDst], #48
    st3     {v18.4s - v20.4s}, [pDst], #48
    st3     {v21.4s - v23.4s}, [pDst], #48
    st3     {v24.4s - v26.4s}, [pDst], #48
    st3     {v27.4s - v29.4s}, [pDst], #48
    b.gt    1b

    add     pRed, pRed, stride
    add     pGrn, pGrn, stride
    add     pGrn, pGrn, stride
    subs    batch, batch, #1
    mov     count, #(640*360)/32
    b.gt    1b

.balign 8
    ldp     q8, q15, [sp], #32
    ret
.endfunc
.end
```

---

It's quite a long one, and it will take considerably longer than the `uint8` one above.

Please note that it will scale extremely well to multi-core execution.

The function prototype is:

`void alquimista_ndarray_to_matrix_float(float *pDst, uint8_t *pSrc, uint32_t batch);`

Comment: Thank you for the code! I am assuming this handles the single image case: so if I am working with a batch, do I provide the pointer to the starting locations of each 640x360x3 image block?

Also, out of curiosity, if I wanted to perform the normalization beforehand, would it be possible to scale this up to handle float values instead of uint8_t?

Comment: @HighVoltage Yes to question #1, but why would you want to do the normalization in the first place? The performance hit is huge if you do something in float.

Comment: Darknet requires the pixel values be encoded between 0 to 1, which is also a standard 'pre-procecessing' step for a lot of convolutional neural networks in general.

Comment: @HighVoltage When do you need the float data? Directly after this function? Then you can do it simultaneously which would be much faster than calling two separate functions consecutively.

Comment: Yes, after this function: once I am done with this 'rearrangement' for all the images, Darknet expects me to provide the float data for the next steps. As my original implementation was sequential, I was just dividing the values by 255 while rearranging them.

Comment: @HighVoltage Ok, I'll amend the function so that it does both in one shot.

Comment: @ I fixed a nasty bug in the first function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll test this as soon as possible and let you know.

Comment: I tested this with one image and it works great! Quick question about the batch: I see that the prototype states the destination array as float*, so are the images ordered sequentially in dst?

Comment: @HighVoltage Yes, they are stored sequentially.